# Add-Migration fails on WinUI 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, winui

I'm new to `WinUI3` and want to use `EntityFrameworkCore` to my project.
I have configured my `DbContext` like all of my other projects:

```
public class BusinessDomainContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public BusinessDomainContext(DbContextOptions<BusinessDomainContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

At the next step, I added `Dependency Injection` by reading the `Microsoft` manuals.
So I have an `App.Xaml.cs` that looks like below:

```
    public App()
    {
        ConfigureServices();

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        SetupLogger(services);

        string businessDomainConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessDomainConnectionString"];

        services.AddDbContext<BusinessDomainContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(businessDomainConnection);
        });

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Now I tried to run `Add-Migration` command.

```
 Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context BusinessDomainContext -OutputDir Migrations\BusinessDomain
```

It fails on this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'BusinessDomainContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I couldn't found a descriptive solution for this.

My feasible way of doing this was to create an separated console application using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services), and run `Add-Migration` while it was `set as startup project`.

Is there any better solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory

```
public class BusinessDomainContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BusinessDomainContext>
{
    public BusinessDomainContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString");

        return new BusinessDomainContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Suffix, The only problem I have with this solution is that I can't read connection string from App.Config but its absolutely better than having separated project for doing migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that add-migration command only works when this line is removed from your WinUI 3 project file:

```
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

And just re-add after completion..

Comment: There are so many issues with `EFCore` in `WinUI3.` There are some serious issues while it tries to open an `SqlConnection` during debug phase. This issue occurs on `localDB` a lot more than `SQLServer`. I tried to write a separated project as a `WebApi`. Now I'm sending requests to this `WebApi` using `Grpc` to get a desirable performance.